# Easy way to rename all files and folders within a directory and subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning some shell scripting. I need an easy way to rename all folder and file names regardless of file type and case sensitivity.

For example, let's say that I have this file structure:

- Hero Folder

  - Superman Images

    - Superman.jpeg
    - Superman and friends.jpeg
  - superman Videos

    - Superman Video 1.mp4
    - superman video 2.avi

What I want to do is replace the string "super" in all of these with "bat". What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Should the folder names also be renamed?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in the directory:

```
ls | while IFS= read -r -- i; do
mv "$i" "${i/super/bat}"
done
```